# Base64String to ImageSource throws an unhandled exception

Tags: c#, .net, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to load an image by a given base 64 string.

I have the following XAML Image:

```
<Image x:Name="CustomImage"></Image>
```

And I have this method on the class page, whose is called after `InitializeComponent()` in the constructor:

```
public void LoadImage(string imageString)
{
    CustomImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
        return imageString.StringToStream();
    });
}
```

The extension method called:

```
public static Stream StringToStream(this string image)
{
     var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(image);
     using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
     {
         ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
         return ms;
     }
}
```

No exception is thrown by the method, but an unhandled exception is thrown after the code is executed.

What I am doing wrong? I can't catch the exception, because is thrown outside my code.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: "An unhandled exception has occurred." No detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below Code :

```
CustomImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(
                () => new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(imageString)));
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked! But, I can't see the difference, why my code didn't work?
Maybe the using statement that dispose memory stream? I think so.

Comment: @RodrigoGRodrigues see what I told in my answer. In your code you are writting the stream and when you do it the stream stay unable to be read by the `FromStream` method.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the error is that the cursor's position is at the end of the stream.

You can correct it changing your code to be like this:

**The LoadImage method:**

```
public void LoadImage(string imageString)
{
    CustomImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => imageString.StringToStream());
}
```

**The Extension method:**

```
public static Stream StringToStream(this string image)
{
     var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(image);
     return new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
CustomImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String(imageString)));
```